# Що таке "магала"?

Tags: значення-слів

Зустрів такі рядки у авторському [вірші](http://www.poetryclub.com.ua/getpoem.php?id=800229) (жанр - хоку):

> Рідне **магала**.
>   Відходять люди.Тихо
>   і на вулиці....

Цікавить, що означає слово "магала" і чи взагалі воно є українським, чи це слово було вигадане автором вірша? В СУМі даного слова не знайшов, а пошук в Гуглі привів на сторінку про [село Магала](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0). Однак, сумніваюся, що у вірші йдеться про село, бо слово написане з маленької літери (на відміну від села Росошани).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику української мови](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0) Бориса Грінченка знаходимо:

> Магала́, ли, ж. Часть предмѣстья.

Отже, у вірші йде мова про рідне передмістя. Слово не є вигаданим автором, оскільки  бачимо його у словнику наведено вище

Comment: Гдаю, що ваша відповідь може бути вірною, але чому у вірші в цього слова середній рід? Це помилка автора чи можливо у цього слова є ще якесь значення